# MongoEngine document IntField with default not saved properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Im using MongoEngine (0.24.2) to setup my documents on the MongoDB server (5.0).
When using an `IntField` with a default value I noticed that the field doesn't get saved to my document depending on how I create document instances.

```py
class MyDocument(Document):
    version = IntField(default=1)
    foo = StringField(required=True)
    bar = StringField(required=True)
```

Creating an instance using

```py
MyDocument.objects({"foo":"Hello"}).upsert_one(foo="World",bar="ups")
```

result in a persisted document that has the field "foo" and "bar" but not "version", despite "version" having a default value.

I don't understand why this is the case ?

Comment: This seems to point in the same direction, stating that empty fields ( or None ) are not persited in db: https://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/migration_to_v2.html?highlight=version%20field#empty-fields-are-not-created-in-database

Comment: Created an issue https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2694